# Can't use watcher.Filters.Add() function in .sln project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, filesystemwatcher, sln-file

I am creating a project and I am using FileSystemWatcher, however I need to add multiple filters and watcher.Filters.Add() doesn't work. I am using .NET Framework ver. 4.8 and have .NET core 7.0.203 installed.

I have tried updating .NET framework. I have also created a console application which uses .NET 7.0 and .Filters.Add() works perfectly fine. Why won't it work in this code?

```
namespace pro
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Image");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Document");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Video");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Audio");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Web File");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("System File");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Database File");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Presentation File");
        }
        public void Vars(string text)
        {
            var path = text;
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(); 
            watcher.Path = path;
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.FileName;

            if (comboBox1.Text == "Image")
            {
                watcher.Filters.Add("*.txt") //why won't this work?
            }

            if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
            {
                watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            }
            else
            {
                watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
            }
            watcher.Created += OnCreated;
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        }

        private static void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs file)
        {
            string value = $"Created: {file.FullPath}";
        }
        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Vars(textBox2.Text);
        }
        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" means you don't get events or not all events or just certain events or some parts of the code throws exceptions? Please try to be less cryptic.

Comment: When you mean that doesn't compile. Filters has been implemented with Net Core 3 according to the documentation that is way after Net 4.8.

Comment: Hello, sorry for misunderstanding i am in a hurry. It gives error like: "filters isnt a method of filesystemwatcher" also 4.8 framework seems to be the newest version there is for sln? @Ralf

Comment: ".sln" is a Visual Studio Solution file, which has no relation to .NET nor makes a distinction between .NET Framework and .NET (Core). Do you mean something else?

Comment: @CodeCaster basically what i mean is that i have a windows form application. I am trying to use filesystemwatcher method .filters not .filter (without the s) to add multiple filters to the watcher. But .filters gives error that there is no such method. In a differend - console app - i also tried it and it did work

Comment: `.sln project` isn't a thing - `.sln` is the file extension of the solution file, a solution could have a variaty of different projects eg. `c# project` (*.csproj) - and a `c# project` can have variaty of different project types eg. `WPF`, `WinFoms`, `ClassLibrary`, `ASP.net` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why won't it work in this code?

[`FileSystemWatcher.Filters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.filters?view=net-7.0) property is available since .NET Core 3.0, hence it is not available in .NET Framework. Check the [Applies to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.filters?view=net-7.0#applies-to) section (at the moment of writing latest .NET version being [.net-8.0](/questions/tagged/.net-8.0)):

| Product | Versions |
| --- | --- |
| .NET | Core 3.0, Core 3.1, 5, 6, 7, 8 |

Comment: Is there no fix for this except using multiple watchers?

Comment: @AmsterdamGhoul AFAIK - no. Either use multiple watchers with the same handler, or one watcher which will watch everything and perform filtering in the handler.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to everyone for answering.
I have found a better solution than using multiple watchers with same handler or one watcher and filtering in the handler. Apparently you can use [.NET upgrade assistant](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant/tutorial/install-upgrade-assistant) to convert a solution to .NET 7. which will allow the usage of .Filters!

Comment: FYI the upgrade assistant can be installed as a visual studio extension https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant-now-in-visual-studio/